# GitHub Octokit GitHubClient.Repository.Content.GetAllContents never returns

Tags: c#, github, octokit

I am following some sample code for GitHub Octokit and one part is using the GitHubClient.Repository.Content.GetAllContents function. The code is from here:
https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net/blob/main/Octokit.Tests.Integration/Clients/RepositoryContentsClientTests.cs#L95
I don't get any error but it just seems to hang. I am working within my companies firewall. I can use Octokit sample from here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1277348/Using-Csharp-Code-to-Access-the-GitHub-API
where I enter my token and then can see my repos. I just can't seem to execute the Repository.Content.GetAllContents function as it just hangs. Is this a firewall issue or something?

Comment: Can you include a snippet of the code that calls that method and hangs?

Comment: var contents = await _client
    .Repository
    .Content
    .GetAllContents("octokit", "octokit.net", "Octokit");

In the watch window _client is: {Octokit.GitHubClient}. I wanted to show a screen shot but can't figure out how to do that.